# Interpolation in Finite Element Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, interpolation, finite-element-method

I am taking a course about the Finite Element Method, and we are now talking about error estimates (a priori error estimates). My lecturer keeps mentioning 'Interpolation' but I do not think I know what that means and why it is useful.

If the error estimate is to measure the distance between the exact solution and the approximate solution, why do we need to measure the distance between the exact solution and its 'Interpolation'?

Background:

Suppose we have a problem $(P)$: Find $u$ in $V$ such that:
$$a(u,v) = l(v), \ \ \ \ \forall v \in V$$
$V$ is a Hilbert space, $a(\cdot,\cdot) : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ a bilinear bounded and coercive form and $l(\cdot) : V \to \mathbb{R}$ a linear bounded form. By the Lax-Miligram lemma, we have a unique solution of $(P)$.

Let $\{\phi_i^h\}_{i=1}^N$ be a basis of a finite dimensional space $V_h \subset V$. We consider the problem $(P_h)$ in $V_h$: Find $u_h$ in $V_h$ such that: $$a(u_h,v_h) = l(v_h), \ \ \ \ \forall v_h \in V_h$$ We call
\begin{align} 
I_h : V & \to V_h \\ u & \to I_hu
\end{align}
the interpolation of $u$ in $V_h$.

Comment: That is a strange use of that term. It is a projection onto the subspace. Interpolation means to have given a function value table and get values between the table rows in some systematic way so that the resulting function is continuous, ... One could say that from $u$ you extract the function table and then get a function in $V_h$ by some kind of interpolation using the kernel functions of the finite elements, so you name the whole process for the second part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try to do in FEM is basically to find an approximation $\bar{\phi}$ of your true solution $\phi$ to your PDE. The approximate solution can be written as
$$
\phi(x) \approx \sum_{i=1}^{n}N_i \phi(x_i) = \bar{\phi}.
$$
You know only the values of $\phi$ at given points $x_i$. The functions $N_i$ are often refered to as interpolation functions or basis functions, typically the so called hat-function is used in linear finite elements. I am very sure, that your lecturer refers to your solution $\bar{\phi}$ as the interpolation, since it is an interpolation of the real solution $\phi$. The image below [Przybilla 2022] shows how $\bar{\phi}$ approximates $\phi$ with hat-functions.[image: Przybilla 2022]